# Sequelize throws [object SequelizeInstance: tablename] error

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

When I try to add a record into my database, I see `[object SequelizeInstance:feed]` on the browser. It adds records into database but it shows this text.

Why it happens and how can I prevent it?

What's wrong with my code?

Here's my db.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('mydatabasename', 'root', 'root', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    port: 8889,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
    },
    define: {
        timestamps: false
    }
});

var db = {};

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

models.js

```
var feed = sequelize.define('feed', {
        subscriber_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        activity_id: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    {
        tableName: 'feeds',
        freezeTableName: true
    });

module.exports.feed = feed;
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var db = require('../db'),
    sequelize = db.sequelize,
    Sequelize = db.Sequelize;


var feed = require('../models').feed;

router.get('/addfeed', function(req,res) {
    sequelize.sync().then(function () {
        return feed.create({
            subscriber_id: 5008,
            activity_id : 116
        });
    }).then(function (jane) {
        res.sendStatus(jane);
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [express response sendStatus](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendStatus) method which expects an integer of the http status.  The code `res.send(jane)` is probably what you're looking for.